# Python Code Consecutive Letters

Tags: python

```
def consecutiveLetter(str): 
    x=0 
    flag=0 
    while(x<(len(str)-2)): 
        i=ord(str[x]) 
        j=ord(str[x+1]) 
        k=ord(str[x+2]) 
        if((i+1)==j and (j+1)==k): 
            print("String has 3 consecutive letters") 
            flag=1 
            break 
        else: 
            x=x+1 
if(flag==0):
    print("String has no 3 consecutive letters")
```

When I run it in python, it's requiring me to type out consecutiveLetters('then the word').

I just wanted to be able to type the word in and it tell me if it has 3 consecutive letters or not. Please help!

Comment: Python is extremely reliant on indentation and structure. Please format your code appropriately.

Comment: Please format your code properly, as line breaks and whitespace are significant in Python. Indent lines by 4 spaces and they will be formatted as code.

Comment: Please format your code in the original question. The way your code is written, it is syntactically incorrect and cannot be understood or executed.

Comment: You didn't fix it. Edit your original post.

Comment: Sorry I am new here and having a difficult time posting. My apologies. :/

Comment: You code is still incorrect. The body of the `while` loop must be indented. How do we know which statement s belong to the loop and which do not?

Comment: So, what is wrong with you code? (Aside from the fact that you should **never** call you variable `str`, because `str` is a built-in function.) What is your question?

Comment: Basically I am trying to write the code so when I run it, it ask me to enter in a word and it will tell me if it has 3 consecutive letters or not. I don't wan to have to type in consecutiveLetters('THIRSTY') for example. I just want to be able to type the word 'THIRSTY' in and it will tell me that word has 3 consecutive letters. Or if I type in the word 'SLAM" it will tell me that it doesn't have 3 consecutive letters.

Comment: What you wrote is not a question, but a wish. SO is not a coding service. If you want us help with your code, you have to tell us what is wrong with it.

Comment: Hint : `my_str = input('word: ')`

Comment: The issue with it is that it's having me type in something such as this: consecutiveLetter('SMART') and the it tells me if it has consecutive letters or not. i just want to type in something such as SMART and it give me the message if it contains consecutive letters or not. I am assuming I need to remove this portion of my code: def consecutiveLetter(str):

Comment: You can pass your string as an argument `consecutiveLetter(my_str)` ..Wait , i'ii show you

Answer (score 0):

```
my_str = input('word: ')  # get user input 
consecutiveLetter(my_str) # and pass it to your function
```

You could simplify the `consecutiveLetter` function like that :

```
def consecutiveLetter(mystr): 
    for x in range(len(mystr)-2) : 
        if ord(mystr[x])+1 == ord(mystr[x+1]) and ord(mystr[x+1])+1 == ord(mystr[x+2]) :  
            print("String has 3 consecutive letters") 
            return  
    print("String has no 3 consecutive letters")
```

Comment: Thanks so much t.m.adam! I see what mistake I made. Thank you! Thank you! Definitely a lesson learned tonight! :)